# Did a firefighter rescue a cat from a still-burning house?

Tags: government, fire, denmark

From twitter user [@Earth_Pics](https://twitter.com/Earth_Pics/status/325782247196217344):

> Firefighter in Denmark rescues cat from burning house.The way he hugs
>   cat and the expressions of cat says it all.

[image: Fireman holding a cat]

Note: the white stuff is probably snow, not ash.

An image of this was [posted to Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/1cqaek/firefighter_in_denmark_rescues_a_cat_from_a/), and has received at least 1699 upvotes.

There's no news of this incident in English on Google News. (Searched using firefighter cat Denmark)

[Kitty Saved from Fire, Happy Reunion](http://lovemeow.com/2013/01/kitty-saved-from-fire-happy-reunion/) cites a reddit commenter mentioning an article from [JV.dk](http://www.jv.dk/artikel/1512551:Aabenraa--To-paa-sygehus-efter-brand-i-etageejendom-ved-Forstalle). Unfortunately, I can't read Danish, but the sentence mentioning cats is

> På grund af den kraftige røgudvikling måtte flere katte hjælpes ud af
>   brandmændene.

Did a firefighter rescue cats from a house while it was still burning? Or was it more a case of helping them out after the fire had been extinguished?

Comment: The danish sentence translates as: Because of heavy smoke, multiple cats had to be rescued by the firemen. Earlier in the article, it says that the two men in the apartment had been able to put out most of the fire themselves, and that the firemen quickly extinguished the rest of it. Based on the way it's phrased, it sounds like the cats were evacuated after that.

Comment: The full, very short, article (translated): "The firefighters came out in force this afternoon when a fire broke out in an apartment on the corner of Forstallé and Dronning Margrethesvej in Aabenraa. Two men, who was in the apartment, had pretty much extinguished the fire, which had started on the stove. The two had to go to the hospital for observation, because of possible smoke poisoning. The fire had spread to the hood of the stove, but the firefighters quickly got it extinguished. Due to the heavy smoke, several cats had to be helped out by the firefighters."

Comment: The municipal of Aabenraa has now answered the question on their facebook-page:
[Link](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=805848322764126&set=pb.363339517015011.-2207520000.1392023891.&type=3&src=https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1/1010982_805848322764126_354564418_n.jpg&size=500,624) the name of the fireman is Per Heesch, and he actually lives in a small town about a mile from where I live... I thought he look familiar :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have any knowledge of this specific case, but according to the fire official quoted in [this article](http://m.gastongazette.com/spotlight/firefighters-save-puppy-from-fire-speak-to-pet-rescues-1.271483), rescuing animals from burning buildings is a routine part of firefighting practice. I see no particular reason to doubt the present claim.